# Preview not working on using canvas in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I am working `Canvas` and I tried to draw image on canvas but it not showing me on preview window.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DrawImagePreview() {
    val vector = ImageVector.vectorResource(id = R.drawable.xyz)
    val imagePainter = rememberVectorPainter(image = vector)
    Column(Modifier.background(Color.DarkGray).height(100.dp)) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
            translate(left = size.width, top = size.height / 2) {
                with(imagePainter) {
                    draw(imagePainter.intrinsicSize)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Side window where we `Split` in android studio

[image]

I am using Latest android version

```
Android Studio Flamingo | 2022.2.1
Build #AI-222.4459.24.2221.9862592, built on March 31, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b802.4-9586694 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.2.1
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 16
Metal Rendering is ON
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false
    gradle.version.catalogs.dynamic.support=true

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    idea.plugin.protoeditor (222.4459.16)
```